# Trying to pull an entire row from SQL by ID in PHP

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
require("header.php");
$query = "SELECT title,content,poster FROM forum WHERE id=?";
try
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="post.php"');
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

    echo $_GET['id'];

} 
else
{
    die("You didn't put an ID twat");
}
```

So what I want to do with this, is make it so say if the URL is post.php?=1, I want it to pull the entire row for ID 1, and be able to print out the rows title, content, and the poster. Can anyone help me? would be so grateful!

Comment: Capture a $_GET['id'], and do a select * with limit 1?... **Make sure to sanitize the GET data** as it can be used in SQLINJECT style exploits.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// ACQUIRE DATA FROM URL
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $url_id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    $url_id = 1; // default id here - data not present in url
}
// ACQUIRE DATA FROM URL

// ENSURE VALID DATA FOR VARIABLE QUERY
if (!ctype_digit($url_id)){
    $url_id = 1; // default id again - data unsafe
}
// ENSURE VALID DATA FOR VARIABLE QUERY

$query = 'SELECT * FROM forum WHERE id='.$url_id;

// rest of code here

?>
```